# My admob ads are not showing after publishing the app in google play

Tags: android, google-play, admob, ads

When I export my app into a .APK file and I install it on my Android phone, the ads work fine and appear. However, after I published my app in Google Play and reinstalled it, the ads don't show up.

What could be the reason!? 
My ads' Ids are created for a few weeks, they are not new Ids.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in the ended up working on some phones, but not on others. One problem that you might have is that the device you tested doesnt have access to internet, so the ads cant be loaded. One other problem might be that there are simply not enough ads to be shown by google admob, so you dont display anything.

Comment: when I test my app by using the .apk file , ads show up. When I delete the app an install it from google play in the same time and the same device , apps do not show! @pinbu

Comment: check your admob account, see if something is wrong there. Little thing to take care: always use test ads on your test device and if you install your app never click on ads. I received a one month ban for that.

Comment: I checked my account and I found a notification says that I have to enter payment details. Does that effect the appearance of ads in my new apps? @pinbu

Comment: i don't know, just add it, you will need it anyway.

Comment: I have the same issue. If your issue is resolved let us know how the issue is resolved

Comment: I'm facing this issue still, what did you do? App works with release build but doesn't work with same build once signed by google and available in playstore.